# Lua AST within C#

Tags: c#, lua, abstract-syntax-tree, metalua

What is the easiest way to get an abstract-syntax-tree within C# from a Lua script? I'm trying to do a simple static code analysis within C# for a Lua script.

Many existing code analysis tools like LuaInspect are based on [MetaLua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/), but I don't see an easy way to integrate MetaLua within C#. And projects like [Lua for Irony](https://luairony.codeplex.com/stats) seem to be in an alpha stage or the development has stopped years ago.

What would be your suggestion to get an AST for LUA within C# for static code analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try monosharp: http://www.moonsharp.org/

It uses ANTLR to build a C# AST. You will probably have to do some code spelunking though, since its main objective isn't "creating an AST" but actually "interpreting Lua directly in C#".

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Lua code, nothing should stop you from integrating LuaInspect and MetaLua. The earlier versions of MetaLua required some manual work to avoid compilation steps, but the recent versions (0.7+) don't require much work. The generation of AST is as simple as:

```
require('metalua.compiler').new():src_to_ast(src, filename)
```

Note that LuaInspect hasn't been updated to support `lineinfo` format changes in the recent metalua versions, so if you plan on using it with ML 0.7+, you may review [these changes](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/0775e1bcdc1fc7bc90d91f9c476d706d7cb736f7) I made to make it work in the Lua IDE I'm working on.